# Overlaying colour on a JPEG with PHP/GD?

Tags: php, gd

I have a collection of black and white JPEG's stored on my server. These images are symbol based, where the symbol is a collection of black lines on a white background.

I am trying to use GD to replace the black colour with another colour on the fly based on a variable passed. Currently, I am:

Getting the JPEG as: $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgURL),
Converting a HEX code (#FF0000, say) to RGB through PHP,

And then feeding these variables to:

```
private function colourize_image($image, $colour, $contrast = 0) {
    if (!$image) { return false; }

    imagealphablending($image, true);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);

    # Convert hex colour into RGB values
    $r = hexdec('0x' . $colour{0} . $colour{1});
    $g = hexdec('0x' . $colour{2} . $colour{3});
    $b = hexdec('0x' . $colour{4} . $colour{5});

    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $r, $g, $b);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, $contrast);

    # Return the GD image object
    return $image;
}
```

For some reason, the function doesn't work at all (it won't overlay a new colour).

Can anyone advise as to where I am going wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: How is $colour passed? I've never seen this {0} notation for accessing a variable.

Comment: If it's a string like "FFFFFF" for white, you should be using square brackets, not curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

If the color is the only problem, then you could try this:

```
      <php>
      //SNIP
      $color = preg_replace('/^#/','',$color); //Get rid of "#" if it's there
      $r = hexdec("0x{$color[0]}{$color[1]}");
      $g = hexdec("0x{$color[2]}{$color[3]}");

      $b = hexdec("0x{$color[4]}{$color[5]}");
      //SNIP
      </php>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `imageistruecolor` function to find out whether the JPEG you've just loaded is true colour or palette-based. If it's not true colour, you can create a new true color image of the same width and height, and copy the old image over:

```
$width = imagesx($jpeg);
$height = imagesy($jpeg);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopy($jpeg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
```

You should then be able to apply the new colours.